# How to listen the method channel result

Tags: flutter

On firebase service, there are two method onNewToken and onMessageReceived, the code I tried to implement to get the new token and remote message from them on android side, then feedback to flutter side. But I have no idea how to listen the method channel when it has a result.

```
// Service
public class FluttersService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    @Override
    public void onNewToken(String token) {
        ...
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message) {
        ...
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
}

// Plugin
public class FlutterPushPlugin extends BroadcastReceiver
        implements MethodCallHandler, NewIntentListener, FlutterPlugin, ActivityAware {

    // BroadcastReceiver implement
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        if (action == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (action.equals(ACTION_TOKEN)) {
            String token = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_TOKEN);
            methodChannel.invokeMethod("onToken", token);
        } else if (action.equals(ACTION_REMOTE_MESSAGE)) {
            RemoteMessage message =
                    intent.getParcelableExtra(EXTRA_REMOTE_MESSAGE);
            if (message == null) return;
            Map<String, Object> content = remoteMessageToMap(message);
            methodChannel.invokeMethod("onMessage", content);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMethodCall(final MethodCall call, @NonNull final Result result) {
        switch (call.method) {
            case "onToken":
                // How to response the result to flutter side?
                break;
            case "onMessage":
                // How to response the result to flutter side?
                break;
            default:
                result.notImplemented();
                return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use Event Channel for posting data from android/ios to flutter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Event channel for sending an event to flutter from native.

A complete description is provided in the below article.

https://rvsevtag62.medium.com/event-channel-to-listen-to-broadcast-events-from-android-43a813672896